# Why does my code open two windows?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to open a .pdf file in separate tab/window. It's working, but it opens two windows to show the .pdf.The code I used is as follows.

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
string value = btn.CommandArgument;
imfImageFile = LocalStaticData.UniImageResult;
string path = imfImageFile.WindowsPath;

if (path != "")
{
    Session["OpenPDFImage"] = path;                
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Parent.Page, GetType(),
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "openPdf(\"../InvoiceReport.aspx\" );", true);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function openPdf(href) {
    window.open(href);
}
```

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in the page? Does it break twice? Could this be a double postback trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so two issues - I think Emanuele Greco is right that it is being called twice in your page cycle. The second issue is that you are giving it a unique code every time. You should be putting in the same code (not Guid.NewGuid()) to make sure the script only gets added once.

E.g.

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
string value = btn.CommandArgument;
imfImageFile = LocalStaticData.UniImageResult;
string path = imfImageFile.WindowsPath;
if (path != "")
  {
    Session["OpenPDFImage"] = path;                
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Parent.Page, GetType(),
    "InvoiceReportPDFOpenScript", "openPdf(\"../InvoiceReport.aspx\" );", true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emanuele Greco and rangitatanz. Rangitatanz code worked for me.Thanks Again. I have one more question if u know please help. Im using custom pagging in my report list, the pagging is not working for me, i can copy the code for you.

Comment: Prob best to create another issue - link to it in here if you like.